# Using Python requests to consume API that streams XML data

Tags: python, xml, api, python-requests, streaming

I'm pretty new to programming but have gotten some experience. Right now I'm trying to wrap my head around consuming data from an API that returns streaming XML data, the API will stream a complete `<event></event>` element when an event occurs, see my example below.

The API will also send a `<hearbeat></heartbeat>` event every 30 seconds if no event has occurred.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

r = requests.get(url2, auth=auth, verify=False, stream=True)
for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line:
        dec = line.decode("utf-8")
        print(f"line: {dec}")
```

```
Output:

line: <event id="4311" name="ExtractME" type="log" timestamp="1616433400000">
line: <argument value="cu" type="log" id="1"/>
line: <argument value="ExtractMe" type="dc" id="1" logid="516798654936147>
line: </argument>
line: <argument value="" type="dc" id="1"/>
line: </event>
```

In the event log here I've changed the values to `ExtractMe` for the data that I want to get. Any ideas?

I'm using this example;
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is your question?  Is something not working?

Comment: Hello and thanks! Yeah, how would i get the values i replaced with ExtractMe into a single dict and then send that dict on to the rest of my app? Since the events are coming in one line at the time i am strugling with how to extract it

Comment: You use [Python's XML-handling abilities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html) to parse the XML into a data structure.

Comment: Yes, i use that for other parts of the project. 
But in this case i'm getting event logs from the API - and the API is streaming. Every time an event occurs i get the response in the example above and i get it line for line in request.iter_lines(), the problem is i dont understand how to convert that into something python can handle using xml.etree or something else. 

I dont think i get a complete XML data structure when the API streams a event

Comment: Im not creating a new request for each event, i connect to the API once and it sends continuous data streams as events occur, as seen in the above example

Comment: Im not creating a new request for each event, i connect to the API once and it sends continuous data streams as events occur, as seen in the above example.
So when i establish a connection to the API, i get this;
`line: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
And when a event occurs, i get:
`line: <event id="4311" name="ExtractME" type="log" timestamp="1616433400000">
line: <argument value="cu" type="log" id="1"/>
line: <argument value="ExtractMe" type="dc" id="1" logid="516798654936147>
line: </argument>
line: <argument value="" type="dc" id="1"/>
line: </event>`

Answer (score 0):

The stream you are receiving consists of distinct XML documents, each with its own root element `<event>`.  Thus the stream *as a whole* is not itself a valid XML document, as it has multiple roots, and cannot be parsed by any XML parser.

The only way to process this is to buffer an entire event in memory and then parse each event by itself.